# Filter images using Google Earth Engine API with ee.data.listImages()

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-listimages), `ee.data.listImages()` takes optional parameters for filtering the assets using image properties. However, I can't seem to get the image filtering to work... I want this code to filter the assets (original size=2) to return just one.

```
var path = "projects/ee-caseyengstrom/assets/testFolder/"
var assetList = ee.data.listImages(path)
print(assetList['images']) 

var filteredList= ee.data.listImages(path,{
  properties:["num_prop<2", "str_prop=='a'"],
  filter: "properties.num_prop<2"
})
print(filteredList['images']) // not working; should return list of size 1
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/84195ab6054c77dabb35f813ac60130f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listImages` operates on collections, not folders.  Under the covers, it's just calling `listAssets`.

`listAssets` works on collections and folders, but doesn't support filtering on folders.